# PHP - Get integer after word inside string

Tags: php, url

Having this URL string:

```
$URL = "www.example.com/search/brand/model/priceRange:2000-5000/year:1994-2015";
```

How can I identify the price range and the year? So that my final variables result in this:

```
$price_from = 2000;
$price_until= 5000;

$year_from = 1994;
$year_until= 2015;
```

After reading a few posts I've tought of using the explode() method but I'm not sure how to do it having a string like this, thanks in advance

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that the order of the elements in the URL can change, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$result = array();
$url_parts = explode('/', $URL);
foreach ($url_parts as $part) {
    if (strpos($part, ':') && strpos($part, '-')) {
       $sub = explode(':', $part);
       $range = explode('-', $sub[1]);
       $result[$sub[0].'_from'] = $range[0];
       $result[$sub[0].'_until'] = $range[1];
    }
}
```

[demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc3e4bb13d69fc372cf5b1557e97395ba54baae0)

Comment: Hi @cpilko thank you for your answer. As the description says, the elements in the url can change place, I was expecting a code that could identify **priceRange:{Number1}-{Number2}** and **year:{Number1}-{Number2}**

Comment: Try the demo. My code is position agnostic. What URL does it fail on?

Comment: true that, didn't test the demo. Thank you, this is the correct answer